# Cannot Hack Maurice phone with the PC

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

After I watched the first cutscene and killed Maurice, I cannot seem to hack his phone on PC. I tried watching videos and things like that and rebinded the keys. It didn't work. What does it mean by Press and Hold Q? I Pressed Q, and I held Q, it doesn't seem to work. I aim at his phone. The only thing it does is it makes Aiden bring out his phone.

Comment: @Braiam English please?

Comment: Did you ... walk up to/look at the phone? You know, so the Q button shows up above the phone?

Comment: @FEichinger Thanks but I fixed it. I did that already too, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @user74125 Instead of editing the answer into your question, you should post it as an actual answer.  =]

Comment: @GnomeSlice Looking back on this, I did write it as an answer, it just took 2 days to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just launched a new game (did not continue the current one) and it worked.